# Xamarin iOS, Error while presenting a view from the main view controller

Tags: xcode, uiview, xamarin.ios, uiviewcontroller, xcode-storyboard

From the first viewController I am trying to show a second screen.

MobileSettingsViewController mobileView = new MobileSettingsViewController(Handle);
PresentViewController(mobileView, false, null);
I get the exception "Reason: Application tried to present modal view controller on itself. Presenting controller is <ViewController: 0x7fab1f75d730>."

I am not sure what I am missing here. I am new to iOS development. The Custom class and Storyboard ID are set to MobileSettingsViewController. I am missing something basic here and not able to understand what it is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you searched?  There are many existing hits on that error message

Comment: Yeah, tried my best but couldn't solve it as I feel I am missing something really basic here.

Comment: I created a new storyboard and instantiated the viewcontroller from there and it fixed the problem.